# Remove border from DataGridCell in edit mode while text wrap is enabled

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a data grid within which I don't want the grid lines to show at any time.

I've almost got it working with the following code:

```
<DataGrid  
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="Auto" 
        Name="dataGrid1" Width="504" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding SourceCollection}" 
        DockPanel.Dock="Top" GridLinesVisibility="None" 
        CanUserSortColumns="False" 
        ColumnWidth="Auto" HeadersVisibility="None" 
        FontSize="16" FontFamily="Tahoma" MinRowHeight="30">
 <DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding index}" />
     <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding des}" Width="20*">
     </DataGridTextColumn>
 </DataGrid.Columns>
 <DataGrid.CellStyle>
     <Style>
         <Style.Triggers>
             <Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
                 <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="White" />
                 <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Foreground" Value="Black" />
                 <Setter Property="DataGridCell.BorderBrush" Value="White" />
                 <Setter Property="DataGridCell.BorderThickness" Value="1" />
             </Trigger>                  
         </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
 </DataGrid.CellStyle>
 <DataGrid.RowStyle>
     <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
         <Style.Triggers>
             <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                 <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
     </Trigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
 </DataGrid.RowStyle>
<DataGrid>
```

[image]

But as soon as I enable **text wrapping** for the second column, a blue line is shown around the cell in editing mode

```
<DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
<Style>
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
</Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
<DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
    </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
```

[image: Window after enable text wrap]

So how can I remove the blue lines from the `DataGridCell` in editing mode while maintaining the TextWrap option?

Comment: From the looks of the docs it seems a lot like you'll have to paint the editor (the textbox in your case) yourself then.  Sorry this isn't an answer but you should try and find out (1) How editors like a textbox are set into the grid (2) How do you get a handle into painting in them. Update the post here with that info and people will be able to point you further on your quest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For elementstyle you can use TextBlock and for Element editing style you can use textbox and make it borderthickness as 0

```
<DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" >                          
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                    </Style>                     
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style  TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
```

Comment: It works, but the text box is showing some effect on editing. Any idea on how to disable this? <Setter Property="TextBox.Effect" Value="{x:Null}"/> doesn't seems to work